# How to provide 'as const' to string array in function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I provide a generic string array to a function argument and use the generic type in the other function argument?

I want to achieve something like this below:

```js
type Custom<T> = {
  hello: string;
  world: T;
};

declare function builder<T extends readonly string[]>(
  input: T,
  arg: () => Custom<T>,
): void


builder(['hello'] as const, () => ({
    hello: 'some text',
    world: ['1', '2', '3'], // <-- This should fail, as it's not 'hello'!
}));
```

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use `as const` here. You can use variadic tuple types to infer `input` as a string tuple.

```
type Custom<T extends string[]> = {
  hello: string;
  world: [...T];
};

declare function builder<T extends string[]>(
  input: [...T],
  arg: () => Custom<T>,
): void
```

Or you could use `T` as just a string type and type `input` and `world` as `T[]`.

```
type Custom<T extends string> = {
  hello: string;
  world: T[];
};

declare function builder<T extends string>(
  input: T[],
  arg: () => Custom<T>,
): void
```